Converting Landsat raw DNs to reflectance in GEE
I'm working with legacy data, that means Landsats 1,2,3,4 and 5, to create image composites of various vegetation indices. However, Landsats 1-3 are raw images while 4 and 5 are surface reflectance and I want my data in surface reflectance.
How do I convert 1-3 to surface reflectance of ToA reflectance?
